# Inner join não retornando valores do banco

Tags: banco-de-dados, foreach, inner

MEU BANCO

```
CREATE TABLE EXPERIENCIA(
     exp_pri INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     nome VARCHAR(150),
     email VARCHAR(50),       
     exp VARCHAR(100),  
     PRIMARY KEY(exp_pri)
);

CREATE TABLE PRANCHA(
    prancha_pri INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
    tamanho_prancha VARCHAR(8),
    meio_prancha VARCHAR(2),
    litragem_prancha VARCHAR(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (prancha_pri)
);

CREATE TABLE ALTURAPESOESTILO(
    idAltPes INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    idExp INT,
    idPrancha INT,
    altura VARCHAR(4),
    peso VARCHAR(3),
    estilo VARCHAR(15),
    primary key (idAltPes),
    constraint fk_idExp foreign key (idExp) references EXPERIENCIA (exp_pri),
    constraint fk_idPrancha foreign key (idPrancha) references PRANCHA (prancha_pri)
 );
```

MINHA SQL:

```
$query = "SELECT EXP.exp, 
          AEP.altura, 
          AEP.peso, 
          AEP.estilo, 
          PRAN.tamanho_prancha, 
          PRAN.meio_prancha, 
          PRAN.litragem_prancha 
   FROM EXPERIENCIA AS EXP 
   INNER JOIN ALTURAPESOESTILO AS AEP 
   ON (EXP.exp_pri = AEP.idAltPes) 
   INNER JOIN PRANCHA AS PRAN 
   ON (PRAN.prancha_pri = AEP.idAltPes)";

 $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);

 $retorno = array();

 while($experiencia = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    $retorno[] = $experiencia;
 }

 return $retorno;
```

}

INDEX.PHP

```
 include 'banco.php';

    $resultado = array();
    $resultado = BuscaAlgo($conexao);


    foreach($resultado as $valor)
    {
        echo $valor['exp']; print(' '); echo $valor['altura']; print(' '); echo $valor['peso'];  
        echo $valor['estilo']; print(' '); echo $valor['tamanho_prancha']; print(' '); echo $valor['meio_prancha'];
        print(' '); echo $valor['litragem_prancha'];  ?><br> <?php  
    }
```

Eu estou juntando tres tabelas e tentando exibi-las. Porém, tanto ao colocar diretamente no MySql quanto no meu código, não é retornado nada. Não dá erro, mas também nada é exibido.

O que pode ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O inner join só retorna se os dados estiverem em ambas tabelas.

Tente substituir seu inner join por um left join somente para ver quais informações estão faltando.

Comment: Era exatamente isso! O problema estava acontecendo no preenchimento das minhas `foreign keys`. Estavam retornando como `Null`. Modifiquei-as e problema solucionado, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Cara no teu php coloca 
$resultado = mysql_query($conexao,$query) or die(mysql_error());
Assim você realmente vai ver se o erro está na programação ou na query que ta mandando executar.